# Looking for non-conflicting cross-platform keybinding consistency

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim, tmux, irssi, key-binding

I use Mac OS X and Arch Linux and occasionally log into FreeBSD and Debian servers by ssh. My favoured tools are zsh, ssh, tmux, git, vim and irssi. I use iTerm2 on Mac OS X and unicode-rxvt on Arch Linux, where I also use Xmonad as window manager.

Currently **Ctrl+a+n** shifts to the next window in tmux, **Alt+right** shifts to the next in irssi, **Cmd+right** shifts to the next tab in iTerm2, **Ctrl+w+w** shifts to the next buffer in vim and so on. Basically it's just a mess and even though some of these sit in the muscle memory most don't. I'm looking for what could be a consistent keybinding scheme.

In my mind I figure Cmd/Super/Win ought to be used by the OS desktop environment and/or window manager, Alt would be tmux and Ctrl would be vim and irssi. That is going from right to left on the keyboard; Cmd, Alt, Ctrl, and in a somewhat hierarchical way, OS/DE/WM, multiplexer, editor/irc client.

Hence, something like this:

**Cmd+Left/+Right** - Switch workspace (Xmonad)
**Alt+Left+/Right** - Switch tmux window
**Ctrl+Left/+Right** - Switch irssi window/vim buffer

**Cmd+1** - Switch to workspace 1 (Xmonad)
**Alt+1** - Switch to tmux window 1
**Ctrl+1** - Switch to irssi window 1/vim buffer 1

Would this be viable? If not, what uniform keybindings could be used?

---

**UPDATED**
I drew a picture (the colours are horrible, I know) to illustrate what I had in mind. I use Dvorak and replaced vim hjkl movement with dhtn - I'll write left/down/up/right to have it make sense for those who don't use vim. Let's keep it to iTerm2 rather than the entire OS X desktop environment (as well as Gnome and KDE). Basically it comes down to this:
**cmd+left/right/number** for workspaces in Xmonad (or whatever window manager you like)
**alt+left/right/number** for windows in tmux
**ctrl+alt+left/down/up/right/number** for buffers in vim
**ctrl+alt+left/right/number** for windows in irssi
**ctrl+left/down/up/right** for home/pg down/pg up/end in vim, irssi and zsh
[image]
In OS X ctrl+left/down/up/right already works like the above, and alt+left/right moves the cursor by word as opposed to just left/right which moves it by character.

Wouldn't this be fairly logical and intuitive? Am I missing something (conflicting keybindings) or is this doable?

Comment: Ugh, good luck there ... that's the road to paradise, that is ...

Answer (score 5):

I tried putting together a cheat sheet or reference card. After exploring various possibilities I ended up doing the following:

1. Switch from a Swedish keyboard to an English (international) due to the latter being (in my opinion) superior when writing code as well as still being able to type åäö by alt+a/+w/+u+a/+o.
2. Switch from QWERTY to Dvorak because I like how the keys are positioned (no scientific claims here) for programming purposes (had a look at "Programmer Dvorak" but that was too much).
3. Replace vim hjkl movement with dhtn, dD with jJ (mnemonic: "junk"), K with H and the **ctrl+w prefix with ctrl+o**.
4. Some minor additions (and unbinding advanced features to start out easy)...

**TL;DR - stick to using prefixes where available, e.g. ctrl+a in tmux, ctrl+o (Dvorak)/ctrl+s (QWERTY) in vim and irssi. This seems to have the least consequences and be somewhat cross-platform-friendly.**

[image: vim dvorak reference card]